# How to randomize a list with linq from a saved guid?

Tags: c#, linq, cookies

I am reading a guid from cookie to make a list randomized by it with linq and if the cookie is null I generate new guid and save it to the cookie and then use it but the list is not randomized.

Why?

```
var questions = IZBSC.UI.Components.Utility.GetQuestionBank(Model.ExamId);
var random = "";
if (Request.Cookies["Rnd"] == null)
{
    random = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Rnd", random.ToString())
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    };
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
else
{
    random= Request.Cookies["Rnd"].Value;
}

@foreach (var question in questions.OrderBy(q =>random).Take(questions.Count).ToList())
{...}
```

Comment: why you use cookie to store a Guid?

Comment: @LucianBumb So what else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want to store a seed instead of a guid and use code similar to (working example):

```
var list = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

var seed = 3; // CREATE THIS RANDOM NUMBER AND STORE IT INSTEAD OF THE GUID 

var rnd = new Random(seed);

var ordered = list.OrderBy(r => rnd.Next());

foreach(var item in ordered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

So, your code would look like:

```
var questions = IZBSC.UI.Components.Utility.GetQuestionBank(Model.ExamId);
var seed;
if (Request.Cookies["Rnd"] == null)
{
    seed = new Random().Next();
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Rnd", seed.ToString())
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    };
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
else
{
    seed = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["Rnd"].Value);
}

var random = new Random(seed);

@foreach (var question in questions.OrderBy(q =>random.Next()))
{...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same value in `OrderBy` statement, that's why you are getting items in the same order.
You could shuffle the list using something like: `questions.OrderBy(q =>Guid.NewGuid())`, but you want keep same seed value for subsequent request, so you should use `Random` class for this.